# How to change machineprecision digits

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, machine-precision

I am trying to compute `t0`:

```
eq[n_, β_, λ_] := Hypergeometric1F1[1/2 (1 - λ/β), n + 1, β/2]
EDL[n_, β_, k_Integer: 1] := λ /. FindRoot[eq[n, β, λ] == 0, {λ, (2 k - 1) β}]
t0 = Table[EDL[0, β, 1], {β, 50, 100}]
```

When I tried this code I have a problem for $\beta$=(82, ..., 97), the answer is not accurate and I got the error message:

> FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within
>   tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable
>   to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need
>   more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these
>   tolerances.

So, I want to change the machine precision, so I tried:

```
t0 = SetPrecision[Table[EDL[0, β, 1], {β, 50, 100}], 30]
```

But I still have a problem. Please help me to change and set the machine precision.

Answer (score 8):

Setting the option  `WorkingPrecision->30` in  `FindRoot` does exactly what you want and removes the error message.